# Finding a maximal sorted subsequence

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Assume that we're given a set of pairs S={(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)} of integers. What is the most efficient way of computing a maximal sequence of elements (a_1,b_1),...,(a_m,b_m) in S with the property that

a_i <= a_{i+1}

b_i <= b_{i+1}

for i=1,...,m-1, i.e. the sequence is ordered with respect to both components. I can come up with a quadratic algorithm that does the following:

1. We sort the elements of S with respect to the first coordinate, giving (c_1,d_1),...,(c_n,d_n), where c_i <= c_{i+1}.
2. Using dynamic programming, for each (c_i,d_i) we compute the longest sequence ordered with respect to both components that ends in (c_i,d_i). This can be done in linear time, once we know the longest such sequence for (c_1,d_1)...,(c_{i+1},d_{i+1}).

Since we have to perform an O(nlogn) sort in step 1 and a linear search for each index in step 2, which is quadratic, we end up with a quadratic runtime.

I've been trying to figure out whether there's a faster, i.e. O(nlogn) way of generating the maximal sequence from having two sorts of the set S: one with respect to the first component, and one with respect to the second. Is this possible?

Comment: Are we allowed to reorder elements in the original set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it `O(n log n)`.

1. Let's sort the elements of the set in lexicographical order. The first components are ordered correctly now, so we can forget about them.
2. Let's take a look at any sorted subsequence of this sorted sequence. The second elements form an increasing subsequence. That's why we can just find the longest increasing subsequence in the sorted sequence for the second element of each pair(completely ignoring first elements as they are already sorted properly). The longest increasing subsequence for an array of numbers can be found in `O(n log n)` time(it is a well-known problem).

Comment: As I understand it you only need to select elements from the set that can form a maximal sequence, when you find the longest increasing subsequence you are restricted by the existing ordering. What I mean by this is that I assume that you can freely rearrange the elements to get the increasing subsequence, e.g remove an element that separates two increasing subsequences. I assume that based on the fact that there is an initial set of elements and the problem asks to form a sequence out of it, so the ordering is not relevant at any point but in the final sequence.

Comment: @computador7 Yes, according to my understanding elements can be reordered.

Comment: So if you sort lexicographically so that elements that are equal on the first component are sorted based on the second in step 1. then I think that in step 2. you could just remove any term that has d_i < d_{i - 1} in O(n) time.

Comment: @computador7 No, it is not correct. For example, if the second elements are {1, 4, 2, 3}, the answer is {1, 2, 3}, not {1, 4}.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I confused the longest increasing subsequence with Kadane's algorithm which requires the values to be contiguous. I think this solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I really should review basic DP algorithms. Had I remembered the longest increasing subsequence algorithm, this would have indeed been very simple...